# Embed code Brightcove media api

Tags: api, html, publish, brightcove

I am trying to find out a way to access the publishing code of a video on my media api through brightcove, just like the one that you can get on there cloud studio for a player like this one below.

```
<!-- Start of Brightcove Player -->

<div style="display:none">

</div>

<!--
By use of this code snippet, I agree to the Brightcove Publisher T and C 
found at https://accounts.brightcove.com/en/terms-and-conditions/. 
-->

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js"></script>

<object id="myExperience" class="BrightcoveExperience">
<param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
<param name="width" value="960" />
<param name="height" value="445" />
<param name="playerID" value="2164048951001" />
<param name="playerKey" value="AQ~~,AAABzJDWv4k~,nrw5-YJoyhvZYIpODobX62cNFZVSM1ri" />
<param name="isVid" value="true" />
<param name="isUI" value="true" />
<param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />

</object>

<!-- 
This script tag will cause the Brightcove Players defined above it to be created as soon
as the line is read by the browser. If you wish to have the player instantiated only after
the rest of the HTML is processed and the page load is complete, remove the line.
-->
<script type="text/javascript">brightcove.createExperiences();</script>
```

I would like to make this an option in my video metadata section of my api, does anyone have any suggestions where to start.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you can gather the publishing code of an asset via the BC API but it isn't necessary.  What you can do is use variables to replace the only items of that snippet which may change - primarily playerID and playerKey and videoPlayer value (which will indicate which player to use and which video to insert) but also potentially width and height settings.

Let's say you are looking to dynamically swap out the video (assuming you will always use the same player), you could do something like this:

```
function get_player($video_id){
$player = '<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js"></script>    
<object id="myExperience" class="BrightcoveExperience">
<param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
<param name="width" value="960" />
<param name="height" value="445" />
<param name="playerID" value="2164048951001" />
<param name="playerKey" value="AQ~~,AAABzJDWv4k~,nrw5-YJoyhvZYIpODobX62cNFZVSM1ri" />
<param name="isVid" value="true" />
<param name="isUI" value="true" />
<param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />
<param name="@videoPlayer" value="'.$video_id.'" />
</object><script type="text/javascript">brightcove.createExperiences();</script>';
return $player;
}
```

And then just call the function using the id of the video you want to display in this player.  The same could be applied for swapping out players and sizes.

```
echo get_player('my_video_id');
```

the @videoPlayer param tells the player which video to load.
This [documentation](http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/player-configuration-parameters) may help.